env variable is not set during build on Vercel
While deploying a monorepo app with turbo build on vercel, there are erros about accessing the env vars. On local It can access the env var in .env.local, however on vercel platform it suddenly stopped working and started complaining about it.
all env variables are set in the dashboard

but during build it it fails to access the env variables.

Why it can't access whose env vars?

I've had a similar problem before - I think the issue happens when you're trying to access env vars in the incorrect environment (i.e. server-side vs client-side).
From the docs:
Non-NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser (the client runs in a different environment).

Are you trying to access DATABASE_URL in a server side component by any chance?

I access it from api route.ts files. Will double check it

I am having this issue just now when I started using @t3-oss/env-core in an api route file. I've even double checked that all the env variables are set on vercel and they are set for production.
Does the build not have access to env vars?

Figured it out.
When using turborepo, you have to set it in the globalPassThroughEnv

Thank you! It worked. Answer this question and I’ll approve
